E2026 Constant expression expected
Переношу компонент с Rad 10.3 в RAD 11. наткнулся на ошибку.
 const
{$IFDEF FPC }
// Not so wide version of RT_RCDATA
  RT_RCDATAW = #10;         
{$ELSE }
// Wide version of RT_RCDATA
  RT_RCDATAW = pWideChar(#10);  // ошибка здесь Е2026
{$ENDIF }

не могу понять причину. В 10.3 работало.
Заменил на RT_RCDATAW: PWideChar = #10;теперь выдает ошибку в строке
constructor createRes(const name: wString; resType: pwChar = RT_RCDATAW; instance: hModule = 0);

в хелпе вроде разрешено
const WarningStr: PChar = 'Warning!';


Типизированные константы нельзя использовать в константных выражениях. Сделайте RT_RCDATAW = PWideChar(10); либо измените тип resType: Integer и объявите RT_RCDATAW = 10;
